# ie9 angular $http response showing as numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, internet-explorer

In IE9, I'm getting data from an API using angular's `$http`.  The response header for content-type is:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

When I view the response body in Developer Tools, I see the JSON response as expected.  However the response in the `$http` success function is a bunch of numbers `123,34,95,105,100,34,58,34,53...`

Any idea why this isn't json? This is only with IE 9.

Comment: Even though it's not supposedly the correct way: Have you tried to set the content type to `text/html`?

Comment: Yeah, tried that and `text/json` - same deal.

Comment: I tried using `$.ajax` with jQuery directly and it works.  It's something related to angular.

Comment: Right, I said I tried that AND `text/json` - both didn't work.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [$http success callback data undefined in IE](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4738)